# Ruby on rails // Require specific parameters for specific actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to rails, i'm trying to create an action for updating an existing record with some required fields. Right now i got something like that:

```
def assembling_params
      params.require(:device).permit(:assembling_time, :operator_assembling_name)
end
```

Right now it check if my device param is present and whitelist only 2 attributes and it's working. 
But how can i do to put these 2 attributes required by my action ? (I don't want to put it in the model validation since these attributes aren't present when i create my object)
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify as many requires as you please.

This may look ugly, but it does the job.

```
def assembling_params
  device_params = params.require(:device).permit(:assembling_time, :operator_assembling_name)
  device_params.require(:assembling_time)
  device_params.require(:operator_assembling_name)
  device_params
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use in appropriate controller:

```
before_filter :validate_params
```

And method:

```
def required_params
[:some_attribute, :another_attribute]
end

def validate_params
unless (require_params - params.keys).count.zero?
  # do something
end
```